# "I am a degree holder now" or "I am now a degree holder"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

Which one is correct?

> - I am a degree holder now.
> - I am now a degree holder.

Comment: Should be on another network-  ELL.

Answer (score -1):

```
*I am a degree holder now.* 

*I am now a degree holder.*
```

Both are correct but personally, the latter gives an air of confidence

Licentiate:[a person who has received a license, as from a university, to practice an art or profession. 2. the holder of a university degree intermediate between that of bachelor and that of doctor, now confined chiefly to certain continental European universities.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/licentiate)

Comment: You do like to post obscure words here! But you must admit this is totally irrelevant to OP's question about the placement of "now".

Comment: Jog brain -I just came in from a run ;-)

Comment: Okay, I cancelled my downvote following your edit (the second half is still irrelevant lol :). But personally I'm not convinced about "the latter gives an air of confidence". I think it's a *slightly* unusual word-order (compare *"I'm married now"* with *"I'm now married"*), so we look for *any* interpretation that's a bit less likely than whatever would be the most obvious one if "now" were simply tacked on to the end of the statement as usual.

Answer (score -2):

I found a lot people use the latter on many movies. As I see it, it's a kind of emphasis or something like that.